# Symfony2: Splitting routing.yml in multiple files

Tags: symfony

I have a **routing.yml** file where I define the routes of my bundle. My routing file is growing bigger.

Is there a way to split the routing.yml file in multiple files? Eg:

- user_routing.yml
- vehicles_routing.yml
- cost_centers_routing.yml

NOTE: I am using Symfony 2.2;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The routing.yml can split by multiple files. You can include separate routing files in your routing.yml file.

```
acme_demo_user:
  resource: "@acmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing/user_routing.yml"
  prefix: /user
acme_demo_vehicles:
  resource: "@acmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing/vehicles_routing.yml"
  prefix: /vehicles
.............
.............
```

Comment: the "prefix" parameter is not required :)

Comment: @Snoozer I used this routing for Symfony 2.2 I think. Please make necessary changes according to new version, Thanks.