# Symfony3: Splitting routing.yml in multiple files

Tags: yaml, url-routing, symfony

I have a routing.yml file where I define the routes of my bundle. My routing file is growing bigger.

Is there a way to split the routing.yml file in multiple files in Symfony3 ?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355385/symfony2-splitting-routing-yml-in-multiple-files) but it is for Symfony2. The path aren't the same.

In Symfony2, we did like this :

```
app_catalogs:
  resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing_catalog.yml"
  prefix: /catalogs
```

I tried this but it doesn't work (my file is in the same level than routing.yml) :

```
app_catalogs:
    resource: "app/config/routing_catalog.yml"
    prefix: /catalogs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(When not importing from a bundle), you should use paths relative to the current directory of the configuration file, so for example:

```
app_catalogs:
    resource: routing_catalog.yml
    prefix: /catalogs
```

Comment: Do you know what it is for Symfony4?  I tried adding admin/routes.yaml and including it inside the default routes.yaml and to no avail.